# How can I get my watch history with YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since 2016, watch history is no longer available via the YouTube Data API v3 (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history)

Are there any workarounds to get this information from an authenticated user?

Comment: Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered
1.Summarize the problem
2.Provide details and any research
3.When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed the YouTube Data API no longer provides the watch history playlist of any channel. I also am adding that there's no other way to obtain this kind of info from the API.

However, there is a workaround for that: use [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/). That page allows you to select the item `YouTube and YouTube Music`, then to obtain via your Google account a link to a downloadable archive that contains your watch history among other things.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about Google Takeout, it did the job for me!