# How to get YouTube watch history through YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, deprecated

I know that it's deprecated for almost 4 years now. I'm interested if there are some updates on it? maybe there are now some roundabouts to get watch history data? Maybe it's somehow possible to get it through my google activities? (I know there is a way to download it to your drive through google takeouts, but that does not solve my problem, because the only thing I can get is access token from google through OAuth 2.0, which I can later use to obtain data through youtube data API. I.e I can't log in to google account)

Comment: You don't need to rely on undocumented behavior of YouTube (as implied by the answer below). Just access Google Takeout and get [your watch history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63213538/8327971) in form of a (possible big) HTML file packaged among other nice things within an archive.

Comment: thank you but that solution doesn't solve my problem anyway, I updated my question to clarify

Comment: did you managed to get the watch history using any API ?