# Youtube API - Generate required Oauth to retrieve my own watch history playlist

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to accomplish a simple task. Namely, I want to call the youtube API and get all the videos in my private watch history. I'll use Python for that and then store the data in an SQLite file and that's it.

I do not plan to publish this data anywhere. I just want to analyse my own viewing patterns.

I am aware that there is a Google service called "google takeout". However, I want to use this project as an opportunity to create an ETL pipeline so I must use the API approach.

Unfortunately, I am struggling with the fact that I need to set up an OAuth consent to access this info. But since I am not building any website nor app I don't get how to achieve this.

Did any of you succeed at a similar project and would be willing to share what has to be done in order to access one's own watch history through the YouTube API?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, @Yrden, this kind of info you need accessing through YouTube Data API -- the watch histrory -- is not made available by any endpoint. [Google's Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) is the only way to get that info from YouTube.

Comment: For the other part of your question -- that about OAuth -- I recommend to use the Google's [Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client): just browse through the [sample code](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python) provided by Google. The OAuth 2 authentication/authorization flows are not that hard to implement at all.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here's the SO answer to your question: [How can I get my watch history with YouTube Data API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213016/how-can-i-get-my-watch-history-with-youtube-data-api-v3)