# Is there a way to use Youtube API for realtime history browser verification?

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I want to make a personal project with C# that consists on using the Youtube API to verify in my browser if I'm watching too many youtube videos in an X period of time (ex: If I watch more then 10 shorts in under 5 minutes, the program would alert me). It's supposed to be a simple project to consume any API for practice.

The problem is, I've been reading the API documentation and it doesn't mention verification of the history playlist and using 'time' as a parameter (ex: Get videos from history browser that were watched in the last 5 minutes).

Is there another approach that I'm not considering?

I'm still searching for approaches to see if it's a possible project. If there is no way to achieve that initial idea, I'll try another project to consume another API.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63213538/4139809 ?

Comment: the youtube api doesnt support sharts to start with, not does it include user history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YouTube data api doesnt support History or shorts.

If you live in Europe you could use the [Data portability api](https://developers.google.com/data-portability) to get your YouTube Activity from that.  Currently thats only supported in Europe.

Or you could manually do a Google Takeout to get the data.

Comment: Yeah, I looked into some topics after saying that history browser was removed since 2016...I'll look into that option of using Google Takeout, thanks!!